# Why am I only able to print one object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Doing some practice runs on codecademy, and came across the following problem:

I am able to only console.log "Steve Jobs" and all his info, but I want to also

include "Bill Gates." If anyone knows how to do this that would be great, or

any alternatives to the following code:

```
var friends = {};

friends.bill = {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
    number: "(206)555-5555",
    address: ['One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052']
};


friends.steve = {
    firstName: "Steve",
    lastName: "Jobs",
    number: "(206)777-7777",
    address: ['Apple Rd.', 'Cupertino', 'CA', '90210']
};

var list = function(list) {

    for (var dale in friends) {
        console.log(dale);
    }

}

var search = function(name) {
    for (var key in friends) {

        if (name === friends[key].firstName) {
            console.log(friends[key]);
            return friends[key];
        }
    }
};
```

***OK, so when I run this code, only Steve gets printed. It should also print Bill.***

Comment: Tip: indent your code properly. It makes your life much easier in the long run, and helps people on sites like this be able to help you.

Comment: how are you calling your functions?

Comment: Whey I run this code there is no output at all ... you are not calling anything. Please show the code you use to actually call something

Comment: I assume you call `list(friends)` - but then there are two lines (bill and steve)...

Comment: Run the code in console. This is what I get "Object {firstName: "Steve", lastName: "Jobs", number: "(206)777-7777", address: Array[4]}"

Why is it not printing Bill as well?

Comment: On the console it prints the result of the last command you execute. This is the line with `friends.steve = ...` so it prints the `steve` part of the object

Comment: The console always outputs the last expression.
Add `'';` at the end and you get an empty string... But that's console-specific - in fact, your code does not output anything (at the moment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/rarozizega/1/edit?js,console) from your code with the addition that I called `list();` right at the end. If you run the code using `CMD+Enter` you will see that the output is as expected, printing out both **bill** and **steve**

Comment: Ok, but do you know why if I run the code as is, I get this: "Object {firstName: "Steve", lastName: "Jobs", number: "(206)777-7777", address: Array[4]}"

And not Bill's info too?

Comment: running the code as is should print nothing. ```list``` and ```search``` are the only functions that use ```console.log``` and neither is being called currently in your code. If something gets printed it might be that CodeAcademy calls one of your functions behind the scenes

Comment: Ok they answered above as to why  it is printing that.

So I ran your code, now I am getting Steve, Bill. and "undefined."

Why am I getting undefined?

Comment: That's due to JSBin. If you were to replace ```list()'``` with ```console.log('hello, world')``` the console would still log ```undefined```. It's just JSBin, you shouldn't worry about it. If you want more in-depth to this it's because ```console.log``` return ```undefined``` which in turn gets printed

Comment: That's the same as above. A console takes the last expression and prints it. Your last expression returns undefined...

Answer (score 0):

Copy/pasted the code in the console and calling:

```
search('Bill');
```

Works just fine for me, how are you using this code?

Comment: I am running the code as is, and am getting this: "Object {firstName: "Steve", lastName: "Jobs", number: "(206)777-7777", address: Array[4]}"

Why is it also not printing Bill's info?